# I can not use launch.json to debug python files in vscode, but in almost two weeks ago，it is ok

Tags: visual-studio-debugging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yvm4.png)
Now, when i use the launch.json to debug, it comes out "Time out waiting for launcher to connect"

I have tried to delete old launch.json file and create a new file, but it is not work!